# Statistics - Regression

Tags: statistics

A sample of $40$ women is obtained and their heights in inches and pulse rate in beats per minute are measured. The linear correlation coefficient is $0.221$ and the equation of the regression line is $y = 18.5+0.860x$ where $x$ represents height and $y$ the pulse rate. The mean of the $40$ heights is $62.8$ inches and the mean of the $40$ pulse rates is $73.2$ beats per minute. Find the best predicted pulse rate of a woman who is $65$ inches tall (use a significance level of $0.01$).

The answer is $73.2$ beats per minute.

Can someone explain the steps involved in arriving at the solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer because I think something is wrong with the
information given. Perhaps you can make some sense of the approach anyway.

Regression line: y = 18.5 + 0.86x.  If x = 65, then the predicted height is
18.5 + 0.86(65) = 74.4, which is close but not exactly the given answer 73.2.

The regression line should go through the center of the data cloud. Let's
check that: 18.5 + 0.86(62.8) = 72.508, not 73.2. Strange.

Also, the number 73.2 shows up in two different places in your statement.

Something is not right here. Suggest you check all of the numbers carefully
and edit the problem as necessary.

In addition, I do not see the relevance of the correlation coefficient o.221
or of the significance level 0.01. Sometimes word problems have information
that is not needed to make sure you're not just plugging aimlessly into
formulas, but these numbers do seem out of place.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the relevance of the correlation coefficient $0.221$ and of the significance level $0.01$ here.

This is made to test the following hypothesis:

$H_0: \rho = 0$

against $H_1: \rho \neq 0$,

where $\rho$ is the population correlation coefficient

Here we reject $H_0$ if the absolute value of $r$ is
greater than the critical value of the correlation coefficient.

Basically, at the significance level of $0.01$, the critical value of the correlation coefficient is $r_{critical}=0.402$, when the number of samples, $n=40$ which is greater than $0.221$ and therefore we fail to reject $H_0$.

Therefore at $0.01$ significance level, we cannot establish the linear relationship between the variables, and thus in the solution, you find $73.2$ as the answer, which is the mean of the $40$ pulse rates (since it cannot be calculated using the height value). This is my understanding of the problem and please correct me if there is some misunderstanding on my part. Thanks :)